# Stream API - need to iterate over the List and compare with Map. Write result in different Map

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

```
public class ProductInStockRequest {

    private String productId;

    private Integer requestedQuantity;
}
```

I have a List

```
    requestList.add(new ProductInStockRequest("100", 5));
    requestList.add(new ProductInStockRequest("200", 11));
    requestList.add(new ProductInStockRequest("300", 33));
    requestList.add(new ProductInStockRequest("400", 55));
```

I have a Map<String, Integer> productInDbMap = new HashMap<>();

```
    productInDbMap.put("100", 10);
    productInDbMap.put("200", 10);
    productInDbMap.put("300", 44);
    productInDbMap.put("400", 77);
```

I created new Map<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<>();

I need to go over each element in List and check if for related productId I have enough quantity or not and write result in responseMap

Trying to do something like this:

```
    requestList.stream().map(requestedItem -> {
        int quantity = productInDbMap.get(requestedItem.getProductId());

        if (quantity >= requestedItem.getRequestedQuantity()) {
            responseMap.put(requestedItem.getProductId(), "order-able");

        } else {
            int availableQuantity = quantity - requestedItem.getRequestedQuantity();
            String s = String.valueOf(availableQuantity);
            responseMap.put(requestedItem.getProductId(), s);
        }
        return responseMap;
    });
```

No luck, please advise

Comment: Why do you want to do this in streams? I think you'd do better keeping a running sum in a traditional loop.

Comment: you need to understand that there are 2 types of operations on streams: intermediate and terminal, and also that streams are lazy. `map` is intermediate operation and without calling a terminal operation on the stream it will not be executed. that is the primary reason why you have no luck so far with the code you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start with something like this:

```java
        Map<String, String> responseMap = requestList.stream().map(requestedItem -> {
            int quantity = productInDbMap.get(requestedItem.getProductId());

            if (quantity >= requestedItem.getRequestedQuantity()) {
                return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(requestedItem.getProductId(), "order-able");
            } else {
                int availableQuantity = quantity - requestedItem.getRequestedQuantity();
                String s = String.valueOf(availableQuantity);
                return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(requestedItem.getProductId(), s);
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

In general, never modify anything from inside the stream or lambdas in general. The compiler will allow it in this case (and will complain in case of modifying a variable), but it's always a bad practice and unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly collect to map:

```java
Map<String,String> responseMap = requestList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ProductInStockRequest::getProductId, requestedItem ->  {
            int quantity = productInDbMap.get(requestedItem.getProductId());

            if (quantity >= requestedItem.getRequestedQuantity()) {
                return"order-able";
            } else {
                int availableQuantity = quantity - requestedItem.getRequestedQuantity();
                return String.valueOf(availableQuantity);
            }
        }));
```

Your approach will work fine if you use forEach:

```java
Map<String,String> responseMap = new HashMap<>()
requestList.stream()
            .forEach(requestedItem ->  {
                int quantity = productInDbMap.get(requestedItem.getProductId());

                if (quantity >= requestedItem.getRequestedQuantity()) {
                    responseMap.put(requestedItem.getProductId(), "order-able");

                } else {
                    int availableQuantity = quantity - requestedItem.getRequestedQuantity();
                    String s = String.valueOf(availableQuantity);
                    responseMap.put(requestedItem.getProductId(), s);
                }
        });
```